# How to rotate a triangle about its center?

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, angle

```
    document.onkeydown = function (event) {
        switch (event.keyCode) {
            case 74:
                //player presses "j"
                px = player.calculateCentreX();
                py = player.calculateCentreY();
                x1 = rotateX(player.x1,player.y1,35,px,py);
                x2 = rotateX(player.x2,player.y2,35,px,py);
                x3 = rotateX(player.x3,player.y3,35,px,py);
                y1 = rotateY(player.x1,player.y1,35,px,py);
                y2 = rotateY(player.x2,player.y2,35,px,py);
                y3 = rotateY(player.x3,player.y3,35,px,py);
                
                player.setPoints(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3);
                break;
                
            default:
                break;
        }
    };
    
    function rotateX(cx,cy,angle,px,py) {
        x = Math.cos(angle)*(px-cx) - Math.sin(angle)*(py-cy) + cx
        return x
        }
        
    function rotateY(cx,cy,angle,px,py) {
        y = Math.sin(angle)*(px-cx) + Math.cos(angle)*(py-cy) + cy
        return y
        }
```

I am using the above to try to rotate a triangle (the player) about it's centre whenever the user presses "J". The setPoints method simply sets the triangles x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3 values to the updated points. Whenever the user presses J, the triangle does rotate but grows in size - can someone point out what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are using wrong argument order: function is defined with `center, angle, point` sequence

```
cx,cy, angle, px,py
  ^             ^
center        point
```

but you call it with `point, angle, center` sequence

```
px = player.calculateCentreX();
py = player.calculateCentreY();
x1 = rotateX(player.x1,player.y1,  35,  px,py); !!!!!
                     ^                   ^           
                   point                center calculated above
```

As a result, former center is rotated around vertices